# derivatives of Kinetic Energy

Tags: calculus

I read that derivative of Kinetic Energy function = $F.v$ while I got $mv$ when I differentiated it with respect to velocity. 
The way I did it is:

$\frac{dK}{dv} = \frac{1}{2} m . \frac{d}{dv} v^2$

So I assumed that the mass is fixed and I differentiated the squared velocity by taking the (2) down and subtracting (1) from the exponent, which gave me $2v$ for $\frac{d}{dv} v^2$

Would you clarify the correct derivative of Kinetic Energy as well as the $F$ variable? And what does the derivative in this case represent?

Answer (score 1):

The derivate of kinetic energy respect to the time $t$ is $Fv$:

$$K'=mvv'=mva=Fv$$

In general $v$ depends by time so the **total** derivative of $K$ is $Fv$, i.d. the instantaneous power.

Comment: Can I just differentiate with respect to v, not t?

Comment: Yes you can derivate it also respect to $v$.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of kinetic energy is [**momentum**](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/196365/why-are-force-momentum-and-kinetic-energy-derivatives-of-each-other), which has the equation $p=mv$.

Comment: So if I have the mass = 2, then the slope will be 2v, right?

Comment: @ZainOmar The instantaneous slope of the Kinetic Energy is $2v$, yes.

Comment: how can I describe the change in Kinetic Energy with respect to change of velocity? I'm talking about the slope being 2v. How is x and y changing?

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{d v^2}{dt}=2v\frac{dv}{dt}$$

$$\implies \frac{dK}{dt}=\frac{1}{2}m\frac{d v^2}{dt}=mv\frac{dv}{dt}$$

but $$m\frac{dv}{dt}=F$$

thus

$$\frac{dK}{dt}=Fv$$

which represents the power of force $F$ ,( in Watt).

Comment: why should I assume that the function is with respect to time? Can I simply differentiate v^2 as 2v?

Comment: @ZainOmar you will not get the power in Watt.